# header fixed but responsive to content

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sample problem :
http://jsfiddle.net/yrbvw473/43/

I just want the margin content from top is balance. if in small width browser, the header will be had two row line, if like this i want the content get more distant from top. and if three header have 3 row the distant top and content get more..

i had the code with css :

```
    @media (max-width: 990px) {
    .heads_search{
        top:40px;
    }
    #space_top{
        height:50px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .heads_search{
        top:60px;
    }
    #space_top{
        height:160px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 390px) {
    .heads_search{
        top:100px;
    }
    #space_top{
        height:200px;
    }
}
```

but it didn't 100% right, so if anyone have more good idea?

Comment: Hello, Can you please explain your question? I am unable to grasp the point.

Comment: open the sample and resize the browser to small, the the content didnt respont of the title if the title have more height...

Comment: set min-height for header.

Answer (score 0):

add a small script to adjust the margin-top attribute. try something like this.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  $('#content').css('margin-top', 50 + $('#header').height());
});
```

Comment: still didn't works..
margin between content is still depend of top, 
my goal is if it resize to smaller the content will depend on title not the top..